# How to return a data from the previous role using a case when statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
Account number --------- updated date -----  change date ----- item clothing    

0001134600000089783 ---- 2016-02-11 ----  2016-06-24  ----  L
0001134600000089783  ----2016-02-11----  2016-07-11  ----   L
0001134600000089783---- 2016-07-13----  2016-07-13----      J
```

I was trying to achieve a --> Case when updated_date <= change_date then 'select item clothing code L (as I want the previous item code to be displayed everytime) else display nothing end) as previous_item_code.

Comment: Please show the expected output for the above sample data

Comment: I don't get what your asking for sorry. Is it that you want to get the record before the most current record is that correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "as I want the previous item code to be displayed everytime"?

Answer (score 0):

Based of what I can make I of the question;

row Numbers might help to get the data set you need

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms186734.aspx

```
Select
*
From
(
Select *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Account Number] ORDER BY  [update date] DESC) AS Row_n


) as I
Where Row_n in(2)
```

Sorry for the poor formatting and not so grand code. On a mobile so can't verify.

Hope this helps a little

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Declare @Table Table(Accountnumber varchar(50),updateddate date,  changedate date, itemclothing    varchar(10))
insert into @Table values 
 (0001134600000089783,'2016-02-11','2016-06-24','L')
,(0001134600000089783,'2016-02-11','2016-07-11','L')
,(0001134600000089783,'2016-07-13','2016-07-13','J')
```

I assume that your expected query would be 
Case when updated_date <= change_date 
then 'select item clothing code with value = L 
else display nothing end
as previous_item_code.

```
SELECT Accountnumber
    ,updateddate
    ,changedate
    ,itemclothing
    ,CASE 
        WHEN updateddate <= changedate AND itemclothing='L'
            THEN 'L'
        ELSE ''
        END AS previous_item_code
FROM @Table
```

Note: if you don't want (AND itemclothing='L') then you can remove it in Case when.

Comment: You can either vote up or select answer that best suits you to solve your problem.